# Update updated_at attribute in mongo on each update using Morphia Java

Tags: java, mongodb, playframework, morphia, database

I want to update `update_at` attribute in MongoDB for each update on a document so later I can retrieve documents based on the last update_at filed. There are two ways I came across for this scenario.

1. Update update_at in each DAO call like

   ```
   public void updateMemberDetails(Long memberId, Sring email) {
   UpdateOperations<Member> ops =   getDs().createUpdateOperations(Member.class);
   Query<Member> query = basicQuery(memberId);
   ops.set("email", email);
   ops.set("update_at", new Date());
   getDs().update(query, ops);
   }
   ```
2. Other ways is to call Mongo's life cycle method in model (http://mongodb.github.io/morphia/1.4/guides/lifeCycleMethods/)

   `@PrePersist
     public void prePersist() {
       update_at = new Date();
     }`

Problem :- 
Method 1 works perfectly fine but the only disadvantage of method 1 is I have to add `ops.set("update_at", new Date());` in each DAO update method that I don't want to update in each method.

In method 2 `prePersist()` method called only in `operation db.save()`, prePersist() method is not called in db.update() operation. So I am not able to update date when DAO method call db.update().

Answer (score 1):

This is less performant than using `update()` since it will load the object in order to do a save, but what about:

```
public void updateMemberDetails(Long memberId, Sring email) {
  Datastore ds = getDs();
  UpdateOperations<Member> ops = ds.createUpdateOperations(Member.class);
  QueryImpl<Member> query = basicQuery(memberId);
  Member member = query.get();
  member.setEmail(email);
  ds.save(member);
}
```

It also gives you the option to add validation logic into the `setEmail()` function.

Note: the `get()` method is in `QueryImpl` via the `QueryResults` interface and not part of the `Query` interface.